# Is it possible to load in GCP Vertex AI Dataset a set of files along with their training target?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

In my local application, looking to implement a retrain mechanism for a text classification ML model, I need to load a set of file from a previously created dataset along with their target class.

I found just [this Google resource](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-import-data-text-classification-single-label-sample#code-sample) that says it's possible to load files with the `import_data` method, but it's not possible to load the associated labels.

Has anyone found a workaround or something else to do such thing?

Additional info: 
I'm using Python 3.8.5 
I'm using the `aiplatform` package version 1.25.0

In alternative to the presented Google tutorial, I tried to use

- the module google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets with the TextDataset object but I failed
- the parameter `annotation_labels` in the [ImportConfig object](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.ImportDataConfig) but I suddenly understood it is not for specifying the annotation name or the training target of the data to import

Comment: have you gone this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/text-data/classification/prepare-data#csv) which talks about how to take input files for text classification?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan yeah sure, but I need to do this in Python and not from the GCP UI

Comment: yes, from python client itself. You will be providing a GCS URI(code referenced in your question) of the input CSV (mentioned in the above link).

Comment: @SakshiGatyan ok i'll try this way. I suppose the CSV should be in the GCP format of ``"SET; file_path; label"``. Is it correct?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Hi! I tried what you proposed by calling ```ds.import_data(
            gcs_source=[the_gcs_path_to_the_csv],
            import_schema_uri=aiplatform.schema.dataset.ioformat.text.single_label_classification,
            sync=True,
        )``
and the elements are loaded but WITHOUT THE ASSOCIATED LABEL. And I absolutely need it